# how do I override create action with variables generated inside the controller in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the code that I have written in the create action of Payments Controller.

```
user_id=Performer.find_by_first_name(params[:payment][:first_name]).user.id
email=Performer.find_by_first_name(params[:payment][:first_name]).user.email
@payment = Payment.new(user_id,params[:payment][:desc],params[:payment][:amount],email,params[:first_name])
#@payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (5 for 0..1)
```

I cannot just pass the values of as such so I need to change them before I save it in the table. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only accepts an hash of attributes:

```
@payment = Payment.new(
  user_id: user_id,
  desc: params[:payment][:desc],
  amount: params[:payment][:amount],
  email: email,
  first_name: params[:first_name]
)
```

Since you are using `Rails 4`, I encourage you to take a look at [`strong_parameters`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters).

### Changing the values before saving them in the db

You can either use a `before_save` callback or defining custom accessors.

#### 1. Using `before_save` callbacks:

If you want to change the values before saving them in the database, you can use a `before_save` callback:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :change_values

private

  def change_values
    self.amount = amount.do_something
    # etc.
  end
end
```

API documentation:

- [`ActiveRecord::Callbacks`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

#### 2. Using custom accessor:

Or you can define custom accessor:

**2.1 With `read_attribute` and `write_attribute`**

```
def amount=(dollars)
  write_attribute :amount, dollars.do_something
end

def amount
  read_attribute(:amount).do_something
end
```

API documentation:

- [`read_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read.html#method-i-read_attribute)
- [`write_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-write_attribute)

**2.2 With virtual attributes:**

```
def amount_in_dollars
  amount.do_something
end

def amount_in_dollars=(dollars)
  self.amount = dollars.do_something
end
```

Railscasts:

- [Virtual Attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes)
- [Virtual Attributes (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised)

Comment: Amazing answer I appreciate it. I am using Strong parameters, Am I doing something I shouldn't do when using Strong parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @payment = Payment.new(:column_1 => value/params[:],:column_2 => params[:desc])
```

if it is a form submit

```
@payment = Payment.new(param[:payment])
```

out side form submit

```
@payment.column_1 = value
```